# How to set up metadata database for Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hive can have its metadata and stores the tables,columns,partitions information over there.
If I do not want to use the hive.Can we create a metadata for spark same as hive.
I want to query spark SQL (not using dataframe) like Hive (select, from and where) Can we do that? if yes, which relational DB can we use for metadata storage?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we create a metadata for spark same as hive.

Spark does this for you and you don't have to use a separate installation of Hive or even just part of it (e.g. a Hive metastore).

Regardless of the installation of Apache Spark you use, Spark SQL uses a Hive metastore internally for the same purpose as Hive does (but the metastore is now part of Spark SQL).

> if yes which relational DB can we use for metadata storage?

Anything that Hive supports, e.g. Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL. The configuration is pretty much as you would do with a separate Hive installation (which is usually the case in such enterprisey installations).

You may want to read [Hive Metastore](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-hive-metastore.html).

Answer (score 0):

Spark is essentially a distributed computation system instead of a distributed storage. Therefore, we mostly use Spark to do the computation work, which needs the metadata from different storage.

However, Spark internally provides an InMemoryCatalog to store the metadata if it's not configured with Hive.

You can take a look at [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html) for more information.